# How do I connect to data base from servlet. I have tried the following code, but control goes to exception everytime

Tags: java, database, servlets, database-connection

How do I connect to data base from servlet. I have tried the following code, but control goes to exception everytime.

```
   try
            {
            int num_rows = 0;
            Connection con = null;
            Statement st = null;
            Statement search = null;
            ResultSet rs = null;
            ResultSet searchRS = null;

            // Connecting to the database
            PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/employees","root","");
            st = con.createStatement(); 
            rs = st.executeQuery("select employees.first_name,employees.last_name,employees.gender,employees.hire_date,departments.dept_name,salaries.salary from employees,departments,salaries,dept_emp where employees.emp_no=salaries.emp_no AND dept_emp.emp_no=employees.emp_no AND dept_emp.dept_no=departments.dept_no AND salaries.to_date='9999-01-01' AND (employees.first_name='"+Sname+"' OR employees.last_name='"+Sname+"')");
            //Retrieval of data from result set retrieved from database

            String[][] str = new String[10][6];

                while( rs.next())
                {
                    str[num_rows][0] = rs.getString("first_name");
                    str[num_rows][1] = rs.getString("last_name");
                    str[num_rows][2] = rs.getString("gender");
                    str[num_rows][3] = rs.getString("hire_date");
                    str[num_rows][4] = rs.getString("dept_name");
                    str[num_rows][5] = rs.getString("salary");
                    num_rows++;
                }

                if(num_rows <10)
                {
                    isLast = true;
                    var = 0;
                }   

            request.setAttribute("listvalue",str);
            request.setAttribute("rows",num_rows);
            RequestDispatcher RequestDispatcherObj =request.getRequestDispatcher("SearchName.jsp");

            RequestDispatcherObj.forward(request, response);

            out.flush();
            con.close();
            var = var +10;
            }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: are you sure you want to have database code in your servlet?

Comment: also, ALWAYS include the stacktrace if you talk about exceptions

Comment: you don't declare type for var in your code, but anyway we're need exception

Comment: you need to correctly alias your column names e.g. select employees.first_name should be select employees.first_name as first_name , only then can you read some value in rs.getString("first_name");

Comment: Get rid of the lines `PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();` and `out.flush();`

Answer (score 1):

Your string array can hold 10 records; probably you are getting more than that from the database.

You may try this-

```
while( rs.next() && num_rows < 10 )
```

In case you need to collect all the records, better use some collection like List.

Comment: And some custom object instead of a `String[][]`.

Answer (score 1):

For me looks like the line

```
RequestDispatcherObj.forward(request, response);
```

is creating the problem. It is forwarding the request to some other place. The `requestdispatcheobj` may have closed the `out` object. So after that use of `flush() and write()`  will lead to an `IllegalStateException`.

```
out.flush();
con.close();
var = var +10;
```

So make sure this is not the case.

Comment: That is the point of `RequestDispather#forward(request,response)`.

Comment: You use `forward` to forward to a jsp resource to render your response. Why would that cause the error?

Comment: Ok, But it will leave the `out` and `con` objects in open state.

Comment: It will not. At some point, `forward` returns execution, and `flush` and `close` will be executed.

Comment: Ok, so I dunno what the RequestDispatcher uses to write to the response. You might be right in the sense that `response.getWriter();` screws up if you then call `response.getOutputStream()`, throwing an `IllegalStateException`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: Ok, I got your point. One thing I just noticed in the question that the 'out' variable is not being closed. Only the `out.flush()` has been called. Will that cause any problem?

Comment: @Digbijay IMO Not enough to throw an exception in the code he's shown us.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: I have updated my answer. Please take a look if it right or atleast better.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletResponse.html#getWriter(). This throws the `IllegalStateException`, not the `flush()` or `close()`

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: Yes, I just got confused between `getOutputStream()` and the `getWriter()` methods. Thank you.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis You wrote (quote): "At some point, forward returns execution, and ...". Actually `forward` **will not return control to the caller**. Read here: [difference between forward and include](https://www.coderanch.com/how-to/java/ServletsFaq#3). Also here: [Include vs. Forward of the Servlet RequestDispatcher](http://www.theserverside.com/tip/Include-vs-Forward-of-the-Servlet-RequestDispatcher)

Comment: @informatik01 What do you mean by the `control` and `caller`?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Of course the code that calls the *forward*. In this case, if it the servlet,  it is probably *doGet()*/*doPost*

Comment: @informatik01 Then you are completely wrong. How would the exception get caught, or a finally block? Try it yourself. Execution stacks don't just rearrange themselves.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Are you trying to say that two respectful Java  resources are wrong???

Comment: @informatik01 Unless they mean something completely different, yes. Try it yourself. In a `doGet()`, put `System.out.println("hello"); request.getRequestDispatcher("some.jsp").forward(request,response); System.out.println("world");` See what you get. If by control, you mean you can't write to the response, then I agree with you/them, since it should have been commited.

Comment: @informatik01 All `forward` is doing is rendering the jsp and writing it to the `OutputStream`. It's not some magic that removes method calls from the stack.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Yes, you are right. Calling sysout after `forward` worked. I have to think about it

Comment: @informatik01 All it means is that `forward` commits the response while `include` doesn't.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Well exactly that is the point. I looked in the OP's code and seems he's not manipulating the ouput **after** calling `forward`. I thought he was trying to output **after** calling *forward*. **My fault**, sorry

Comment: @informatik01 That's possibly one of his errors. The fact that he is calling `response.getWriter();` and then doing a `forward` might flag something that would later throw an exception.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Yup. One hardly needs getting PrintWriter if he is going to `forward`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Your "At some point, forward returns execution..." confused me in a way, that I thought you meant after committing the response it returns and "you can again write something to the output" kind of thing. My attention is lost, I have to go to sleep. Sorry again, man ))